# Cannot convert the "node" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Diagnostics.Process" when creating a PowerShell alias

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of aliases for tasks I run frequently, like this ones:

```
function bye {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $args[0]
}

function p {
    Set-Location -Path C:\Users\Goncy\Documents\projects
}

function ni {
    npm install @args
}

function nid {
    npm install @args --save-dev
}

function kill {
    Stop-Process -Force -Name $args[0]
}
```

all of them work except by `kill`, I get this error when running `kill node`.

```
Stop-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "node" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Diagnostics.Process".
At line:1 char:6
+ kill node
+      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Stop-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

I tried wrapping it on quotes, brackets, etc. But PowerShell is clearly not my thing.

Comment: `kill` is an alias for `Stop-Process`, use any other name or remove the alias in the current scope with `Remove-Alias kill` before invoking your custom function

Comment: That was it, thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I mark it as correct? @MathiasR.Jessen